# The Main Purpose of Events in C#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I've been examining one of my c# books and I just saw a sentence about Events in C#: 
 **The main purpose of events is to prevent subscribers from interfering with each other**.

Whatever it means, yeah actually events are working pretty much like delegates. 
I've been wondering why I should use events instead of delegates.

So is there any one who can explain the bold part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The choice wouldn't really be between a delegate and an event - they're completely different things. You could, however, expose a public *property* or a public *field* which had a delegate type. I assume that's what you really mean.

Suppose `Button.Click` were a public field or property instead of an event. One piece of code could then subscribe to an event, and another could then write:

```
// Invalid with events, valid with properties
button.Click = null;
```

thus wiping out the original event handler. Likewise other code would also be able to *invoke* the event handlers:

```
// Invalid with events, valid with properties
button.Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

even though the button hadn't been clicked. This is clearly a violation of encapsulation. The only reason to expose `Click` to other code is to allow them to register interest in button clicks and register disinterest later - and those are exactly the abilities that events provide.

Think of events as syntactic sugar around two methods. For example, if we didn't have events then `Button` would probably have:

```
public void AddClickHandler(EventHandler handler)
public void RemoveClickHandler(EventHandler handler)
```

The violation of encapsulation goes away, but you lose some of the convenience - and everyone has to write their own methods like that. Events simplify this pattern, basically.

Answer (score 10):

An event can only be invoked by the class defining it, whereas a delegate can be invoked from whomever has access to it. This here is what I believe the bold text means.

Also, an event can be defined in an interface, whereas a delegate cannot (as you would declare the delegate as a field).

I recommend giving [this link](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) a read, as it explains it quite nicely and has a few more examples other than the above mentioned.

Comment: You could declare the delegate as a property, of course. That would be a more appropriate analogy.

Comment: I've just had a look at that article - I'm not keen on it as it makes it sound like events are just modified delegate-type fields. There's nothing to say that an event has to be backed by a field of that type *at all*. They're more like properties than fields.

Comment: @Jon - Fair, can understand that.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a delegate to NULL which causes it to 'forget' every function that is subscribed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many eventhandler to your event as you want.

Comment: Delegates are multicast too. Indeed, an event is usually backed by a single field of the relevant delegate type.

Comment: I think it's actually a fairly common myth that delegates are singlecast. Many C# developers that I know think that the main difference between the two is that delegates are single-cast whereas events are multi-cast, but it is not so!